# Calling xmllint from QProcess return wrong StandardOutput

Tags: qt, xmllint

I am running xmllint using QProcess with this code:

```
QString program = "xmllint";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "--xpath";
    arguments << "\"//table_data[@name='" + tableToSearch + "']./row[./field[@name='rowuuid' and . = '" + UUIDToSearch + "']]\"";
    arguments << dataFile;
QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess();
    myProcess->start(program, arguments);
    myProcess->waitForFinished(-1);
    QString serror = myProcess->readAllStandardOutput();
    QString serror2 = myProcess->readAllStandardError();
```

If I run the same command in a terminal I get:

```
<row>
                <field name="surveyid">782be47c-2f05-430c-adb9-29fd0631417d</field>
                <field name="originid">FORMHUB-JSON</field>
                <field name="meta_devid">865770021186061</field>
                <field name="start_time">2017-06-06 11:23:36</field>
                <field name="survey_date">2017-06-06 00:00:00</field>
                <field name="date_yyyymmdd">20170606</field>
                <field name="subscriber_id">640021068988925</field>
                <field name="phone_number" xsi:nil="true"/>
                <field name="end_time">2017-06-06 12:54:58</field>
                <field name="onfarm_country">T</field>
                <field name="onfarm_subnatarea">CS</field>
                <field name="onfarm_village">105</field>
                <field name="onfarm_enum">105</field>
                <field name="householdid">TCS1500</field>
                <field name="householdid_key">TCS1500_20170606</field>
                <field name="bent_general">0</field>
                <field name="bext_general">1</field>
                <field name="rowuuid">b93c6113-7508-42aa-8549-267f0956b935</field>
        </row>
```

But myProcess->readAllStandardOutput() returns:

```
//table_data[@name='birdentext_maintable']./row[./field[@name='rowuuid' and . = 'b93c6113-7508-42aa-8549-267f0956b935']]
```

I modified the code to use readyReadStandardError signal just in case more data is sent later on but I get the same.

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: I think you need a space between --xpath query and dataFile

Comment: I had an extra double quotes. Now it works fine....